# New in Ubuntu, after installation

Tags: usb-installation

I just downloaded Ubuntu through my USB, and I removed Windows. Is it necessary that I have the OS of Ubuntu for my saved USB or can I delete it?

Comment: Keep the live USB version of Ubuntu. You may need it later.

Comment: @user68186 okey, thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the Ubuntu installer off the USB by formatting it with gnome disks or gparted, but I highly recommend saving it in case your machine fails to boot, or if something doesn't work properly, etc. For example I only had one USB at the time with the Ubuntu flavour Xubuntu on it. After installing it I formatted the USB, I then installed a Nvidia driver for my graphics card. After rebooting I could not use it at all and I was thinking to myself, "Man I shouldn't of formatted that USB!".If you really need to use a USB for something else just use another or buy a new one they're really cheap.

Comment: You don't need to use an Ubuntu live USB drive for repairing a problem with the Nvidia graphics driver. It's easier to bring up a virtual console after starting to boot Ubuntu and fix Ubuntu from there.

Answer (score 1):

After the Ubuntu installation is completed reboot the computer to the new Ubuntu installation and check if Ubuntu works properly. Then you can delete the Ubuntu OS on the USB drive and use the USB drive for something else. Alternatively you can keep Ubuntu on the USB drive because you might need it later for tasks like repairing the bootloader or resetting a lost administrative password.